# Model Binder & Hidden fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, defaultmodelbinder, html.hiddenfor

I have a simplified test scenario useful for asking this question: A Product can have many Components, a Component can belong to many Products.  EF generated the classes, I've slimmed them as follows:

```
public partial class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Component> Components { get; set; }
}
public partial class Component
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

The creation of a component is accomplished via these controller actions:

```
public ActionResult Create(int ProductId)
{
    Product p = db.Products.Find(ProductId);
    Component c = new Component();
    c.Products.Add(p);
    return PartialView(c);
} 

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Component model)
{
    db.Components.Add(model);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

and the view returned by the GET method looks like this:

```
@model Test.Models.Product

<fieldset>
    <legend>Product</legend>
    <div class="display-label">Name</div>
    <div class="display-field">@Model.Name</div>
</fieldset>

@Html.Action("Create", "Component", new {ProductId = Model.Id}) 
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=Model.Id }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

From which can be seen that the component creation is handled on the same page via the above `Html.Action` - the code for that view follows:

```
@model Test.Models.Component
@using Test.Models

<script type="text/javascript">
    function Success() {
        alert('ok');
    }
    function Failure() {
        alert('err');
    }
</script>
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Component", new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "Post",
    OnSuccess = "Success",
    OnFailure = "Failure"
}))
{
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Components</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Products.First().Id)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Products)
        @foreach (Product p in Model.Products)
        {
            @Html.Hidden("Products[0].Id", p.Id)
        }
        @foreach (Product p in Model.Products)
        {
            @Html.Hidden("[0].Id", p.Id)
        }
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="go" />
}
```

ok.  so this is what I'm struggling with: I need the `model` parameter of the [HttpPost]back to get properly populated i.e. it should contain a Product, since I can't create the new component with a null product.  To get the product I need to look it up via the product's id.  I expect I should be able to do:

```
model.Products.Add(db.Products.Find(model.Products.First().Id));
```

or some such thing, which relies on `model` receiving the id.  This means the view has to place the id there, presumably in a hidden field, and as can be seen from my view code, I've made several attempts at populating this, all of which have failed.

Normally I prefer the *For methods since they become responsible for generating correct nomenclature.  If .Products were singular (.Product), I could reference it as `x => x.Product.Id` and everything would be fine, but since it's plural, I can't do `x => x.Products.Id` so I tried `x => x.Products.First().Id` which compiles and produces the right value but gets name `Id` (which is wrong since the model binder thinks it's `Component.Id` and not `Component.Products[0].Id`.

My second attempt was to let `HiddenFor` iterate (like I would with `EditorFor`):

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Products)
```

but that produces nothing - I've read that this helper doesn't iterate.  I tried `x => x.Products.First()` but that doesn't even compile.  Finally, I decided to abandon the *For and code the name myself:

```
@foreach (Product p in Model.Products)
{
    @Html.Hidden("Products[0].Id", p.Id)
```

and though that looks right, the postback doesn't see my value (`Products.Count` == 0).  I saw in some posting that format should look like `[0].Id` but that doesn't work either. grr...

I gather I could code it like this:

```
@Html.Hidden("ProductId", p.Id)
```

and then redeclare my controller action like this:

```
[HttpPost] ActionResult Create(Component model, int ProductId)
```

but that seems eecky.  it's hard to believe this is so difficult.  can anyone help?

- e

p.s. I have a project I could make available for download if anyone cares

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of writing those `foreach` loops try using editor templates:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Components</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>

    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Products)
</fieldset>
```

and inside the corresponding editor template (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Product.cshtml`)

```
@model Product
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)
```

Comment: ohhhhh........ that is just brilliant.  if I had a bunch of credits to give you'd get them right now.  laughing... I must be so dense the solution didn't occur to me.  thanks a bunch!

Comment: one question left in my mind is: why didn't my first loop work?  it generated `<input id="Products_0__Id" name="Products[0].Id" type="hidden" value="1" />` which looks correct but the back end didn't pick it up.  The .EditorFor() approach generates identical output except that it adds the data validation tag attributes...